# Using TestComplete with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, testcomplete

I have installed TestComplete. I have recorded some tests with Firefox and IE. When I tried to record some test with Chrome I faced the problem as below:

"TestComplete Chrome Extension is not Installed or Is Disabled." (Please see the image)
[image]

What to do for using Chrome with TestComplete?

Comment: Removed [tag:google-chrome-extension] since this does not concern extension development.

Comment: @Xan: Yes, It makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You would need an additional step if you have the latest version of Chrome (42).
Since version 42, Chrome blocks all NPAPI extensions by default, including the TestComplete extension. To enable NPAPI support:

In Chrome, navigate to chrome://flags/#enable-npapi.
Under Enable NPAPI, click Enable.
Restart Chrome.

I would also suggest turning off Chrome auto updates and updating manually to ensure you always have a supported version of Chrome installed.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to work with Google Chrome, you need to have the ***File | Install Extensions... | Web | Chrome Support*** extension be installed and enabled in your instance of TestComplete. This extension is installed and enabled by default if you install the Web module for TestComplete.

If you have a trial version, you should have a trial of all modules. In this case, just run the installation program in the Modify mode and select to install the Web module.

If you have a commercial version, additionally make sure that you have a license for the Web module.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try according to your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Even if test complete chrome extension is installed, it won't let you enable it in chrome://extensions window. Even SmartBear agrees that Chrome version 45 and above doesn't support test complete extention.

"Chrome 45 and later: These versions of Chrome do not support the Netscape Plugin API (NPAPI) technology. In TestComplete 10.60 and earlier, the TestComplete Chrome Extension used NPAPI, which is no longer supported by Chrome 45 and later. To test web applications in Chrome 45 and later, you will have to install TestComplete version 11.10 or later where the Chrome extension uses a newer Native Messaging API instead of NPAPI."

Better to refer this article which is available on SmartBear support site, There is a work around available if there is a real need of testing the application on Chrome browser.:
https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/web/general/preparing-browsers/chrome-extension-forced-installation.html#WaDescr